# Getting an event from a combobox when selecting the same item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few HTML pages. The header contains a combo which allows a navigation by selecting different pages : A, B, C, D.

For the moment, I use:

```
combo.change(function(){
  window.location=path;
});
```

But I would like to select A even if A is already selected, which make a kind of reset of the page. I tried the events blur or click, but it's not working the way I would like.

I know it's not a great web design, but it's a request by my client.

Comment: Do you want to run the same code on unselect? If so then you can just use click instead of change.

Comment: Is it feasible to initially always set the combo to a blank item?

Comment: @FlabbyRabbit : I want to moveto the A page when the combo is down. So I click in the combo, then I click in the option. I will check on something like $('select#myCombo option').click(function(){})

Comment: @pimvdb : no because the combo in an information on the current page. That's what I was doing initially, but the client is not easy.

Comment: I think I now understand what you are looking for, and `$('select#myCombo option').click(function(){})` should work for you, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2CzPm/ ... one draw back being it will not work if the user tabs to the select box and uses arrow keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combo.children('option').click(function(){
 window.location=path;    
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z4H5R/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on every browser. It looks like working on Chrome, but not Chromium. It works with FF 5+.

Comment: where is the problem ?? the click event is working rite ??? did you put an alert inside handler ??

Comment: the problem is I guess in the nested <option> that has no event linked on old browser I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the requirement is very simple, there is no direct solution for this. Could have fixed this if all browsers had supported click and key events for **option** tag.

So one solution I have to suggest is using dropkick - a jQuery drop down plugin.

**http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/**

This plugin actually hides the select element and adds a proxy drop down element, in which actually options are li elements with a tag. The plugin is coded in such a way that it triggers change event even if the newly selected option is the current one. You can see it in the first example. It also supports key navigation.

Comment: I guess it works, but you go out of the web standards. However it can be great when you want to add flags in a Countries combobox. I keep an eye on this plugin.

Comment: Ya this doesn't follow web standards. But its very useful and it will not remove the original select element, just hides it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution with Jquery :
The real code with my combo with id='route' is :

```
$("select#routes option").click(function(){
  console.log("Click on "+$("#routes").val());
  window.location= $("#routes").val();
});
```

The *$("select#routes option").click()* means that I click on the  DOM tag into the  tag.
And it Works !

Comment: But will this work in all browsers ? I think click event of option tag is not supported by all browsers.